# How to turn off PS4 controller?

Tags: controllers, ps4

I'm trying to figure out if its possible to turn off the PS4 controller without turning off the system because it pretty much stays on the whole time I'm not gaming and obviously drains the battery pretty quickly.

On the PS3 there was always an option to turn off the controller itself so I'm wondering if I'm missing something. Anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

- Hold PS button
- Go to adjust devices
- Select turn off device
- Pick dualshock 4.

Comment: there you go! lol, i wouldve never found it!. thanks

Comment: No probblem! Glad to help

Comment: Amazing. Reminds me of Windows 8 and the hidden Power Off button.

Comment: Yeah, not under "power" where you would naturally look...

Answer (score 52):

To turn it off manually, you can hold the PS button for 10 seconds. Good for if your screen is off, if it's indefinitely stuck in searching mode, or if you're using it with PC.

Comment: thanks. after you pair your device with windows this is how i turn off my controller when not using it.

Comment: This is much easier than going through all the menus.

Comment: This is the correct answer and should have been chosen as the best.

Comment: is there a faster way to do this for PC? 10 seconds is a long time when Im in a workflow or trying to get out the door.

Answer (score 17):

To have it turn off automatically after not being used for a while:

1. choose the settings option from the menu on the top of the main screen (far right, next to the power symbol, toolbox icon)
2. scroll down and choose 'Power Save Settings'
3. choose 'Turn Off DUALSHOCK 4 Automatically'
4. select 10, 30, or 60 minutes as the idle time before the controller is turned off automatically (selecting off will return it to always-on)